# jQuery - Count number of checked checkboxes with a given Id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a table on it. Two of the columns in the table are checkbox columns. Each has a different Id value. I'm trying to count, via jQuery, the number of rows in the table where one of the checkbox columns (which has an Id value of 'InChecklist') is checked. My JS function looks as follows:

```
function UpdateCount() {
    var totalRows = $('#checklistTable tbody tr:visible').length;
    var totalSeen = $(":input#InChecklist[checked='checked']").length;
    $("#rowCount").text(totalRows.toString() + " species / " + totalSeen + " seen")
}
```

The total row count is fine. But I must not have the syntax correct for the total seen because I cannot get it to count correctly (the value is always zero). If I remove the '#InChecklist', I do get a value greater than zero, but in this case, it's counting the total checked in both checkbox columns, not the one with an Id of 'InChecklist'.

If it helps, the portion of my HTML that renders the checkboxes look as follows. It's MVC5.

```
        <td>
            <input id="InChecklist" name="item.HasBeenSeenChecklist" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.HasBeenSeenChecklist" type="hidden" value="false" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="InLifelist" name="item.HasBeenSeenLifelist" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.HasBeenSeenLifelist" type="hidden" value="false" />
        </td>
```

Comment: As per your selector, `totalSeen` is going to be either 1 or 0 based on its checked property, not more than that...

Comment: @DavidThomas - I'm now showing the rendered HTML. Should have done that in the first place - Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the ID before the :input like this

```
var totalSeen = $("#InChecklist:input[checked='checked']").length;
```

**Edit**

```
var totalSeen = $("input#InChecklist:checked").length;
```

Comment: Yeah it's too early. Should be $("input#InChecklist:checked").length

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

you can try:

```
var totalSeen = $("#InChecklist input:checked").length;
```

selects all the children inputs of `#InChecklist`

alternatively you can use this:

```
var totalSeen=0;
$("#InChecklist input").each(function(){
    if($(this).is('checked')){
        totalSeen++;
    }
});
```

Comment: That generates an 'undefined' - (473 species / undefined seen)